# Import package face_recognition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install face_recognition package but it still shoots an error.

I have installed cmake and tried doing it again but it still does not work:

```sh
!pip install cmake
!pip install face_recognition
```

The installation works. But when I import face_recognition it says module not found.

Collecting face_recognition
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/ed/ad9a28042f373d4633fc8b49109b623597d6f193d3bbbef7780a5ee8eef2/face_recognition-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\pratyush\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\users\pratyush\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 in c:\users\pratyush\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (0.3.0)
Collecting dlib>=19.7 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\pratyush\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (5.4.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-qxe9rn --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 15:42:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    Generator

```
  NMake Makefiles

does not support platform specification, but platform

  x64

was specified.
```

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Pratyush/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-oeubb_/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-2.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in 
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\tools\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1

---

Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
  Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-mm4zcw\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 15:42:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-2.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

```
    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Pratyush/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-oeubb_/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-2.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "c:\users\pratyush\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oeubb_\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\Pratyush\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'c:\\users\\pratyush\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-oeubb_\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=c:\\users\\pratyush\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-oeubb_\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-2.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Pratyush\\Anaconda2\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=c:\\users\\pratyush\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-oeubb_\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-2.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1
THE ERROR MESSAGE
```